# Why can't I use Taylor Series shortcut here

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I am asked to find the taylor series of $g(x)=x^{2}\ln(x)$ about $a=1$.

**My Steps**:
Let $x=1+y$, so $\ln(x)=\ln(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}+\mathcal{O}(y^4)$**(*)**, for $y\to0$

Now subbing into the equation we get, **(*)**$=(x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}+\mathcal{O}((x-1)^4)$.

And then finally taking $x^2$ into account, the taylor series of $x^2$ around $a=1$ is still $x^2$, so therefore we can simply multiply the two series:

Therefore:

$x^2ln(x)=x^2(x-1)-\frac{x^2(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{x^2(x-1)^3}{3}+\mathcal{O}((x-1)^6)$

However using the taylor series calculator:

$x^2ln(x)=(x-1)-\frac{3(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}+\mathcal{O}((x-1)^4)$

**Question**:

What is wrong with my shortcut method?
Is there a rule of thumb for when **NOT** to use shortcuts, and simply calculate the series through the derivatives?

Comment: It looks like you aren't finding the Taylor series, you are finding the Taylor polynomial of order 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the Taylor series of $x^2$  around $a=1$ is :
 $$x^2=\left(1+(x-1)\right)^2=1+2(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\mathcal{O}\left((x-1)^3\right)$$
Of course, the coefficients of the $(x-1)$ terms of power $>2$ are nul. So, the Taylor series is :
$$x^2=1+2(x-1)+(x-1)^2$$
You are allowed to multiply two Taylor series around the same point, thus
$$x^2\ln(x)=\left(1+2(x-1)+(x-1)^2\right)\left((x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}+\mathcal{O}((x-1)^4)\right)$$
and after simplification 
$$x^2\ln(x)=(x-1)-\frac{3(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}+\mathcal{O}((x-1)^4)$$
If you don't proceed like that, you got terms such as $x^2(x-1)^n$ which are not of the form $\mathcal{O}\left((x-1)^n\right)$. So, you don't have a Taylor series on correct form.

Note :

Your result $\quad x^2\ln(x)=x^2(x-1)-\frac{x^2(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{x^2(x-1)^3}{3}+\mathcal{O}((x-1)^6)\quad$ is correct, but this is another kind of series than Taylor series.

If you think of approximate around $x=1$, one can compare 
$$x^2\ln(x)\simeq (x-1)-\frac{3(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}\tag 1$$
$$x^2\ln(x)\simeq x^2(x-1)-\frac{x^2(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{x^2(x-1)^3}{3}\tag 2$$
Graphical comparison to $x^2\ln(x)$ shows that the deviations for $(2)$ are lower than for $(1)$ on a large range around $x=1$. This is an example of approximation with limited Taylor series is worse than with another kind of series. This is not an unusual case.

Answer (score 1):

A Taylor series centered at $1$ is of the type $a_0+a_1(x-1)+a_2(x-1)^2+\cdots$ Yours isn't of this form. You could get something of this form doing$$x^2\log(x)=\bigl((x-1)^2+2(x-1)+1\bigr)\left((x-1)-\frac12(x-1)^2+\frac13(x-1)^3-\cdots\right).$$

Comment: Yes but that expression above $((x-1)^2+2(x-1)+1)=x^2$. In that way I still get a series of the form $a_{n}(x-1)^n$, however, $a_{n}=c_{n}x^{2}$, where $c_{n}$ is just some coefficient.

Comment: I have no idea about what you mean by that.

Comment: @SABOY. The coefficients of a true Taylor series are not function of the variable $x$.